# Why OpenScales show tiles in cache in zoom in/out WMS layer?

Tags: wms, openscales

I use OpenScales to show a WMS layer and it is strange that when zoom in/out sometimes OpenScales show tiles in cache, so Multi-resolution tiles showed in the layer.
When paning the layer, incorrect tiles will disappear. How can I fix this? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

You can force OpenScales to force a refresh using

```
private function refresh():void{
  var date: new Date();
  WMSLayer.params.setAdditionalParam("time",date.milliseconds);
  WMSLayer.layer.redraw(true);
}
```

Source:

http://openscales.org/demo/current/
Layers>WMS 1.3.0